# Accepted answers and top tag answerers

Tags: discussion, tags, answers, accepted-answer, top-users

Are accepted answers playing some role in particular top tag answerers list or only up voted answers are taken into account?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? What exactly are you trying to highlight? Are you asking if accepting an answer depends on high rep of user or based on no.of votes?

Comment: I'm asking if accepted answers on some tag are also taken into account in some way or if only up voted answers can put you higher on top users list for some tag.

Comment: AFAIK, only upvotes on non-CW answers are counted.

Comment: @Pekka that's what I also know, isn't there official explanation about how top users of a tag are being calculated?